# Change Foundation 6 Paragraph Body Font Size

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-6

Any ideas on how to change the paragraph body font size in Foundation 6 (_settings.scss)? Its seems to default at 16px but I was hoping to reduce this to 12px.

I have tried changing $rem-base and $global-font-size to alternate values but it seems to alter the overall sizes of all elements including headings, column widths etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize that it's a bad idea to modify the base font-size, right?  I'm talking in general, not because of anything specific to Foundation.

Comment: @cimmanon thanks for reply on this. All I need to do is reduce size of paragraph font size from 16px to 14px. Just can't seem to locate an answer to this issue.